# Where can I find some MVC User Administration Helpers for AD Users?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, active-directory, .net-4.0, user-management

So I have an MVC 2 app that uses the Active Directory Membership Provider. Authentication works like a charm! Now I need to add some additional screens to allow the users to:

1. Change their password
2. Reset forgotten passwords (email a super secret link or something?)
3. Conditionally add additional users (of course users of a certain role, as determined by another Role Provider).
4. Conditionally disable existing users (ditto on roles).

I'm just looking for some very basic functionality and I'm having trouble finding either any MVC helpers to help with this or even any legitimate .NET libraries to help. We'd be happy to buy something to do this but I've not seen anything that's convinced me as being good!

Does anybody have any suggestions? Surely many others have had to tackle this by now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified code found here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx for my needs.  The `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider` is extremely limited on it's capabilities.  ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.aspx )

Comment: That's a great resource! Just curious, what modifications did you need that this didn't satisfy for you?

Comment: I removed features I didn't need. :D